# How to use a function parameter in a app.get path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

```
AddItem("Axe1Common")

function AddItem(item){

    let text = '/Add$item/:playerid'

    app.get(text,(req,res)=>{

    });
};
```

Shouldn't this be the same has having "app.get('/AddAxe1Common/:playerid',(req,res)"? Why doesnt it recognize the name on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Your string isn't formatted properly, to do what you're looking for, you have to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

For example, in your code:

```
AddItem("Axe1Common")

function AddItem(item){

    let text = `/Add${item}/:playerid`

    app.get(text,(req,res)=>{

    });
};
```